# Avro generated class: Cannot access class 'Builder'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Tags: kotlin, avro

Running

```
val myAvroObject = MyAvroObject.newBuilder()
```

results in a compilation error:

```
Cannot access class 'MyAvroObject.Builder'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

I am able to access other `MyAvroObject` variables. More precisely, methods such as

```
val schema = MyAvroObject.getClassSchema()
val decoder = MyAvroObject.getDecoder()
```

compiles fine. What makes it even stranger is that I can access `newBuilder()` in my `test/` folder, but not in my `src/` folder.

Why do I get a compile error when using `newBuilder()`? Is the namespace of the avro-schema used to generate `MyAvroObject` of importance?

Answer (score 0):

`Check your module classpath` generally means, that your dependencies (which you didn't provide) are messed up. One of them should read `implementation` instead of `testImplementation`, in order to have the method available in the `main` source-set, instead of only the `test` source-set - **but** this may well have to do with the input classes, the output location of generated classes, or annotations alike `@VisibleForTesting` (just see what it even generates). Command `gradlew` can also list the dependencies per configuration. The builder seems to be called `org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder`... there's only `avro-1.11.0.jar` & `avro-tools-1.11.0.jar`. With the "builder" design pattern, `.newBuilder()` tries to return inner class `Builder`.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem today and was able to solve it by adding the following additional source folder

```
<sourceDir>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/avro</sourceDir>
```

to the kotlin-maven-plugin.